# Authenticate user when wants to buy book in Android application

Tags: java, android, http

I had make a bookstore in android  with eclipse  . I have a main page If user click on login icon , go to login and put username and password then press login button,
If  user found  show massage that”user found”and if user doesn't found   show alert message ”not found”
I want if user login  and see message "user found"
When user want to buy book can buy 
And when don’t login can’t buy book

It means when goto user page(the user page is for buy book)
When  user    login  , this page show
And when doesn't login this page goto the login activity
,
I use flag but I don’t know how to use it ? if flag=0  the user dosn't login and if flag=1  user login .but how transfer this to user page?

Can help me please ?
And is there any site for this?

loginactivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Myactionbar {
EditText userNmae,pass;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
Button btnLogin;
int flag=0;

public void gotosearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
    startActivity(intent);}
    public void gotologin() {
        Intent m = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(m);}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    userNmae=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameedittext);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordedittext);


    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "font/bnazanin.TTF");

    //emailtext
    TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernametv);
    ///tv.setText(booksote.utils.DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText("email"));
    userName.setTypeface(font1);
    userName.setTextSize(26);


    //passwordtext
    TextView password1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordtv);  
    //tv.setText(booksote.utils.DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText("password"));
    password1.setTypeface(font1);
    password1.setTextSize(26);



    //login
    btnLogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setTypeface(font1);
    btnLogin.setTextSize(26);
     **btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                      
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });

}

void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/project/login1.php");
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);


        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name",userNmae.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response :" + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//this I use  flag but I dontknow how to use ?

                    flag=1;


            **Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("flag", flag);**

            startActivity(intent);**




                }

            });


        }else{
            flag=0;
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }




}


public void showAlert(){
    LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("not found")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

}

userpage.java

```
public class UserPage extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_page);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int myflag = intent.getIntExtra("flag");


}
```

Comment: If a user can only get to UserPage after successfully logging in, and UserPage is the only place you can buy a book from, why do you need this flag in the first place?

Comment: @Takendarkk  i   want flag for all activity that activity khows the user is login.if flag=0 user dos'nt login and if flag=1 user login

Comment: So a user can use all the activities in your app even without logging in?

Comment: @Takendarkk yes but in one activity (userpage) must logging in ,the userpage is  for buy a book so user should logging in for buy book.

Comment: @Takendarkk  help me please...

Comment: When the user tries to buy a book in UserPage just check if flag == 0 or flag == 1. It looks like you already have the variable being transferred to that Activity.

Comment: @Takendarkk  thanks a lot, but how to do this can give me code please .thanks

Comment: `if (flag == 0) {}` `if (flag == 1) {}` That is the code.